# How does Facebook know about my fake Yahoo account?

Tags: facebook, privacy

I have a Facebook account. About 4 years ago I registered on Yahoo to use Yahoo Answers. I entered entirely fake details. I check my Yahoo email very rarely, maybe once a year.

When I checked today, I see a bunch of spam messages from Facebook, around 300 since June 2012 with 100 in only the last month, titled “Do you know MY_REAL_NAME? Get on Facebook now and add as a friend.”

My question is how does Facebook know about my fake Yahoo account and its email address? I have never shared my Facebook details on Yahoo and likewise never shared my fake Yahoo account details on Facebook.

Also, in some of the messages I get another 9 random strangers listed in the email beside my name with the same ”Do you know X?“ message, mostly girls.

The sender is update........@facebookmail.com and all the links point to facebook.com there is even an unsubscribe button that opens a page on facebook. It very much looks like to me that they are official facebook emails.

Answer (score 2):

It is spam. The sender is just pretending to be Facebook but it is not.

You're fine by just ignoring the e-mails

Comment: I have updated the question. They look like official facebook emails to me.

Comment: I found out that actually I registered with my fake email to create a disposable fake facebook account too. Maybe facebook know this because I used the same IP address to log in to both my real account and the fake account on facebook

Comment: That is a possibility, although the email's subject and content looks like spam.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possibilities here:

1. It is spam. Confirmation of this can be done only upon looking at the complete header of the email you received.
2. You have linked your yahoo account and Facebook account. At some point of time you might have been signed in to your yahoo account and also logged into yahoo with your Facebook account in the same browser session. This led to clubbing of your yahoo and Facebook account.

[image]

3. You associated your Yahoo account with your real email account by the use of "Secondary Email Address".